# AWS ec2 Ubuntu 14.04 - save the *.pme file // or get Host, user & password

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I need a solution to get the *.pme file to my ec2 instance but didnt found anything. Maybe there is another way to do this without the *.pme file ... but I have no idea.

For using meteor-up (https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) I need to configure the server connection and its ask for a username, host and passowrd. The username (I use an ubuntu instance) is **ubuntu** and the host the **public dns** - this seems to work fine. But I dont have a password I guess (do I?) but I am able to add the location of the *.pme file to use this as my "password".

The question is now: Is it possible to add the *.pme File from the AWS EC2-Manager into my instance so I can use it ?

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you mean the `.pem`, not the `.pme`.*

As the last step, when creating an EC2 instance, you generate a key-pair for the instance. It comes in the `.pem` format.

Had you lost the key-pair for your existing instance and you do not want to create a new instance, follow the instructions at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html